# Unix shell iterate over two lists with unequal number of values

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, loops, unix

How would you produce output that loops the second list over the first? Both lists are files with a values delimited by lines.

```
list1:
1
2
5
6
8
10
13

list2:
a
b
c
d

Output:
1 a
2 b
5 c
6 d
8 a
10 b
13 c
```

Comment: Show your attempt at it?

Comment: @Cyrus I wish I could downvote comments like that

Answer (score 0):

Just read the shortest file and store each line in an array.
Then read the second line by line and print the i-th line mod the number of lines.

This is a quick bash solution:

```
while read -r; do
  shortfile+=("$REPLY"); ((i++))
done < /path/to/shortfile
lines=$i i=0
while read -r; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$REPLY" "${shortfile[i++%lines]}"
done < /path/to/longfile
```

Comment: $ readarray
    -bash: readarray: command not found
    $ bash --version
    GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
    Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: That seems to be very close, but does the opposite!

`a 1
b 3
c 4
d 5
a 7
b 9
c 10
d 13`

Comment: @user3486527 you surely can swap the variables in the printf command, right?

Comment: Switching the %s %s to what?